# 'fill in' the missing position in a list with zeros

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

Here's part of the code I am working on:

```
def count_flip(string, init = '0'):
    x0 = init + string
    return sum(x != y for x, y in zip(x0, x0[1:]))

def absorb_counts(results):
    flip_counts = Counter()
    for binary_string, value in results.items():
        flip_counts[count_flip(binary_string)] += value
    return [v for _, v in sorted(flip_counts.items())]
```

The input of `absorb_counts`, `results`, is a dictionary whose keys are binary strings, and values are some integers. This function combines all the values with the same 'flip' in the keys and sorts them in ascending order in the output.  For example:

```
>>> test = {'011': 11, '111': 11, '110': 13, '100': 31, '001': 9, '000': 738, '010': 118, '101': 93}
>>> absorb_counts(test)
[738, 31, 162, 93]
```

The four numbers are 738 (0 flip), 31 (1 flip), etc. (There's an extra `'0'` in the front, given by `count_flip`.)

**Question:** Sometimes my input `results` doesn't have all the possible binary strings. In such cases, the output is a reduced list with missing positions. For example:

```
>>> test_1 = { '110': 13, '100': 31, '000': 738, '010': 118, '101': 93}
>>> absorb_counts(test_1)
[738, 162, 93]
```

How can I 'fill in' zeros in such positions? The output, in this case, would be `[738, 0, 162, 93]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate through `range(int(max(results), base=2))` and initialize all the corresponding keys before you start accumulating the counts.  If you do this, you don't even need `Counter` since you're starting off with a dict of zeroes:

```
def absorb_counts(results):
    flip_counts = {
        count_flip(bin(i)[2:]): 0
        for i in range(int(max(results), base=2))
    }
    for binary_string, value in results.items():
        flip_counts[count_flip(binary_string)] += value
    return [v for _, v in sorted(flip_counts.items())]
```

Comment: You could also do `f"{i:b}"` instead of `bin(i)[2:]`. In addition, you could do `f"{i:04b}"` to get the leading zero for free.

Comment: @Paul M. Thanks for the comment! How can I use `f"{i:04b}"`? Should I do that in the first function?

Comment: Thanks! That helps :)

Comment: @Paul M. I'm not quite familiar with `f"{i:04b}"`, could you point me to some resource for this? Thanks:)

Comment: @ZR- This is the string formatting [mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec). `f"{i}"` is an f-string literal that formats the contents of `i` into a string. `f"{i:b}"` is the same, but the binary representation of `i` is formatted into the string instead. `f"{i:04b}"` is again the binary representation of `i`, but padded with maximally four zeroes.

Comment: @Paul M. Thanks so much :)